# Pivoting a table along with sum of column value when column type is nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot, pivot-table

I have a table with following structure. I want to Transpose it.

```
 BookId    Status   
 ----------------------
 123A      Perfect
 123B      Restore
 123C      Lost
 123D      Perfect
 123A      Perfect
 123B      Restore
 123A      Lost
 123B      Restore
```

I need the transpose table to look something like this.

Output

```
 BookId    Total  Perfect   Restore  Lost
 -----------------------------------------
  123A      3       2         0        1
  123B      3       0         3        0
  123C      1       0         0        1
  123D      1       1         0        0
```

I have tried this

```
select
    BookId,
    sum('Perfect') as Perfect,
    sum('Restore') as Restore
from 
    [dbo].[Orders]
group by 
    BookId
```

But as those are `nvarchar` values, `sum` is invalid. I am getting this error

I have not much hands on pivot. But tried following

```
select *
from 
    (select SellerAddress, ApplicationStatus
     from [Farm_For_Books].[dbo].[Orders]) src
pivot
    (sum(ApplicationStatus)
         for SellerAddress in ([1], [2], [3])
    ) piv;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`conditional aggregation` might be used

```
with Orders( BookId, Status ) as
(
 select '123A','Perfect' union all
 select '123B','Restore' union all
 select '123C','Lost'    union all
 select '123D','Perfect' union all
 select '123A','Perfect' union all
 select '123B','Restore' union all
 select '123A','Lost'    union all
 select '123B','Restore'   
)    
select
    BookId,
    sum(1) as [Total],
    sum(case when Status='Perfect' then 1 else 0 end ) as [Perfect],
    sum(case when Status='Restore' then 1 else 0 end ) as [Restore],
    sum(case when Status='Lost' then 1 else 0 end ) as [Lost]    
from 
    [Orders]
group by BookId;

BookId  Total   Perfect Restore Lost
123A      3        2       0     1
123B      3        0       3     0
123C      1        0       0     1
123D      1        1       0     0
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/EJCQT69565)

Comment: Thanks!! but I am always getting Perfect and Restore as 0

Comment: @TBAG OK, I've added the demo

Comment: Yes it worked. Previously it was group by both which was having problem. Now it worked. Thanks.